# Side Bar - close and open the filter list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a filter sidebar for my site,
I want to be able to open and close the filter lists by pressing a btn.

```js
jQuery('.parent > .children').parent().click(function() {
  jQuery(this).children('.children').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <span>+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I press the list it closes, I want it to remain open.

Comment: Why not just select the spans directly instead of the parent div? Your issue is that the click event on the list items is bubbling up to the parent div, but I see no need for the div to be what you want to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give class to your button and target only this class:

```js
$('.toggler').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.children').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="toggler">+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="toggler">+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="toggler">+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that the click isn't happening on the actual `li`.

Use [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to do nothing if the click is directly on the `li` elements, so adding this to the click handler should do it:

```
if ($(e.target).is('li')) return;
```

```js
jQuery('.parent > .children').parent().click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('li')) return;
  jQuery(this).children('.children').slideToggle(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <span>+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>+</span>
  <ul class="children">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @j08691, my bad I've deleted my answer.